# Run-time error when using dynamic array formula SEQUENCE

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, excel-formula, dynamic

I'm trying to use the SEQUENCE formula in range.formula2 code line but getting a run-time error.
Am I missing something here when using Dynamic Array Formulas?

```
Select Case Weekday(Range("startDate"), vbMonday)
Case 1
 Range("week").ClearContents
 Range("mon").Formula2 = "=IF(ISBLANK(startDate),"",SEQUENCE(1,days,startDate,1))"
Case 2
 Range("week").ClearContents
 Range("tue").Formula2 = "=IF(ISBLANK(startDate),"",SEQUENCE(1,days,startDate,1))"
Case 3
 Range("week").ClearContents
 Range("wed").Formula2 = "=IF(ISBLANK(startDate),"",SEQUENCE(1,days,startDate,1))"
Case 4
 Range("week").ClearContents
 Range("thu").Formula2 = "=IF(ISBLANK(startDate),"",SEQUENCE(1,days,startDate,1))"
Case 5
 Range("week").ClearContents
 Range("fri").Formula2 = "=IF(ISBLANK(startDate),"",SEQUENCE(1,days,startDate,1))"
Case 6
 Range("week").ClearContents
 Range("sat").Formula2 = "=IF(ISBLANK(startDate),"",SEQUENCE(1,days,startDate,1))"
Case 7
 Range("week").ClearContents
 Range("sun").Formula2 = "=IF(ISBLANK(startDate),"",SEQUENCE(1,days,startDate,1))"
End Select
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things:

- You probably want to expand the double quotes in the 2nd parameter of `IF()` to `""""`. If you don't you'll get a run-time error since the function itself does not accept an empty parameter (which is what you are doing if you don't double up the quotes again);
- Why don't you use `Weekday()` in conjunction with [`WeekdayName()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/weekdayname-function)? This saves you all the hassle with `Select Case`. Something like:

  ```
  Range(WeekdayName(Weekday(startDate, 2), 1, 2)).Formula2 = "=IF(ISBLANK(startDate),"""",SEQUENCE(1,days,startDate,1))"
  ```

**Note:** You are currently using an implicit `Worksheet()` object, namely the currently active one. Be sure to getting accustomed to using explicit range objects in the future.

Comment: Thank you so much, expanding the double quotes fixed the error. I will also try the WeekdayName() function.

Comment: Hi @JvdV, to be honest I'm newby to Excel VBA. I tried your 2nd suggestion but it doesn't populate the named range cell corresponding to WeekdayName, result is always the same even I choose different date.

Comment: It works perfectly now, I refer the named range starDate as range ("startDate")